# Requirement: Python 3.6 (64-bit) is not installed

Tags: python, mysql, installation

I already have Python 3.7 installed. I'm trying to download *MySQL* but I don't fulfil the requirements appareantly.

[image: 2 requirements left unfulfiled]

How can I fulfil Python 3.6's requirement without installing the old version?

Comment: There does not appear to be a Python 3.7 version yet available.  Packages compiled with the C interface (which this probably is) will be linked to a version's python library, for example 3.6, so it can't be run with another release.  It is quite normal for the release of 3rd-party libraries to lag several weeks, or even months, behind a new python release.

Answer (score 1):

Go here
https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-371/

The windows 64 bit install
https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.1/python-3.7.1-amd64.exe

Had the same issue until installing the above.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqwdK.png)

Comment: Wonderful, worked for me too. It needs exactly Python 3.7.1. Thank you!